# Setting an ObservableCollection = to a json response

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I am currently writing a Xamarin forms application. The issue I am facing is that I am receiving a Json Response from my API, and storing it in a var JsonReponse. The code is as follows;

```
        string UserId = Settings.CallUserId;
        var client = new RestClient("http://blablablaAPiCall" + UserId);
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var body = @"";
        request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);


        var JsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Flights[]>(response.Content);



        FlightsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Flights>
        {
            new Flights() {Id="1",  SectorStart="1", Registration="A123", 
            Departure="Jhb", OffBlockTime="1242", Arrival="EC", OnBlockTime="1342", 
            TotalFlightTime="0100", InstrumentTime="00"  }
        

        };
```

The class I made looks like this;

```
public class Flights
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string EntryDate { get; set; }
    public string IsMasterId { get; set; }
    public string SectorStart { get; set; }
    public string SectorEnd { get; set; }
    public string AircraftType { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string PicName { get; set; }
    public string PilotFunction { get; set; }
    public string Departure { get; set; }
    public string Arrival { get; set; }
    public string OffBlockTime { get; set; }
    public string OnBlockTime { get; set; }
    public string TotalFlightTime { get; set; }
    public string NightLanding { get; set; }
    public string Instructor { get; set; }
    public string Simulator { get; set; }
    public string NightTime { get; set; }
    public string DayTime { get; set; }
    public string InstrumentTime { get; set; }
    public string ApproachType { get; set; }
    public string NavAid { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string FinalRemarks { get; set; }
}
```

At the top I declared an Obvservable Collection,

```
public ObservableCollection<Flights> FlightsCollection { get; set; }
```

So now the end goal would be for me to set my json response = Observable collection, as you can see I have done it statically, but now how do I do it with my json response?

My json response looks like this if needed,

```
[
    {
        "ID": 15,
        "UserID": 10,
        "EntryDate": "2022/01/02 2:34:20 PM",
        "IsMasterID": true,
        "SectorStart": 1,
        "SectorEnd": 1,
        "Aircraft_Type": "Unclassified",
        "Registration": "aircraft reg",
        "PICName": "Jordan Watts",
        "PilotFunction": "PIC",
        "Departure": "Jhb",
        "Arrival": "EC",
        "OffBlockTime": "00:00",
        "OnBlockTime": "01:15",
        "TotalFlightTime": "01:15",
        "NightLanding": true,
        "Instructor": true,
        "Simulator": true,
        "NightTime": "01:15",
        "DayTime": "00:00",
        "InstrumentTime": "0000",
        "ApproachType": "VOR",
        "NavAid": "nav",
        "Place": "here",
        "FinalRemarks": "this flight was cool"
    },
    {
        "ID": 16,
        "UserID": 10,
        "EntryDate": "2022/01/02 2:44:10 PM",
        "IsMasterID": true,
        "SectorStart": 1,
        "SectorEnd": 3,
        "Aircraft_Type": "Unclassified",
        "Registration": "aircraft reg",
        "PICName": "Jordan Watts ",
        "PilotFunction": "PICUS",
        "Departure": "JHb",
        "Arrival": "EC",
        "OffBlockTime": "00:00",
        "OnBlockTime": "01:00",
        "TotalFlightTime": "01:00",
        "NightLanding": true,
        "Instructor": true,
        "Simulator": true,
        "NightTime": "01:00",
        "DayTime": "00:00",
        "InstrumentTime": "0000",
        "ApproachType": "VOR",
        "NavAid": "nav aid",
        "Place": "here",
        "FinalRemarks": "rhrbdidbf"
    },
    {
        "ID": 18,
        "UserID": 10,
        "EntryDate": "2022/01/02 2:53:56 PM",
        "IsMasterID": true,
        "SectorStart": 1,
        "SectorEnd": 2,
        "Aircraft_Type": "Unclassified",
        "Registration": "reg",
        "PICName": "Jordan Watts ",
        "PilotFunction": "PICUS",
        "Departure": "Jhb",
        "Arrival": "EC",
        "OffBlockTime": "00:00",
        "OnBlockTime": "02:15",
        "TotalFlightTime": "02:15",
        "NightLanding": true,
        "Instructor": true,
        "Simulator": true,
        "NightTime": "02:15",
        "DayTime": "00:0",
        "InstrumentTime": "0000",
        "ApproachType": "VOR",
        "NavAid": "here",
        "Place": "here 2",
        "FinalRemarks": "flight 1 of 2 "
    }
]
```

Comment: use json2csharp.com to create properly typed classes for your json

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableCollection` accepts an `IEnumerable` which `DeserializeObject` can generate. Try this:

```
FlightsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Flights>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Flights>>(response.Content))
```

Comment: This seems to work, now I received a One of the identified items was in an invalid format

Comment: Is there a way for me to select only certain fields with this?

Comment: @JordanReighn The fields it maps are defined in your `Flights` class. Instead of marking all those properties as `string` you need to set them to the correct data type. For example the JSON has `ID` as a number so your model should list the property as data type `int`: `public int Id { get; set; }` Same thing for the boolean properties and the dates (assuming you don't want dates in string format).

Comment: I thought converting them all to a string would do the trick, the only field there that is received as a type int would be the ID, if I hover over my ObservableCollection all the data seems to be correct however I am still getting a System.FormatException: 'One of the identified items was in an invalid format.' exception. What could I look at?

Comment: I also removed the attributes in my class that I did not need,

Comment: @JordanReighn Removing the property from the model should ignore it. It sounds like the deserialization and ObservableCollection creation is working if you see the data debugging. You would need to find where that System.FormatException is being thrown. I assume its further down in your code.

Comment: As jason mentioned , use `use json2csharp.com` to generate c# class with your json , it will create the correct type according to the json , for example , here `ID` should be `int` type and `IsMasterID` should be `bool` type .

Comment: Do I need to mark my question as answered?

Comment: @JordanReighn Yes it sounds like your original issue with creating an `ObservableCollection` is working now. If you have a new problem, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have only some properties , you can create subclass accoring to your needs

```
FlightBase[] flights = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlightBase[]>(response.Content);

 ObservableCollection<FlightBase> FlightsCollection = new ObservableCollection<FlightBase>(flights);
```

classes

```
public class FlightBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SectorStart { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string Departure { get; set; }
    public string Arrival { get; set; }
    public string OffBlockTime { get; set; }
    public string OnBlockTime { get; set; }
    public string TotalFlightTime { get; set; }
    public string InstrumentTime { get; set; }
}
public class Flight:FlightBase
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string EntryDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsMasterID { get; set; }
    public int SectorEnd { get; set; }
    public string Aircraft_Type { get; set; }
    public string PICName { get; set; }
    public string PilotFunction { get; set; }
    public bool NightLanding { get; set; }
    public bool Instructor { get; set; }
    public bool Simulator { get; set; }
    public string NightTime { get; set; }
    public string DayTime { get; set; }
    public string ApproachType { get; set; }
    public string NavAid { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string FinalRemarks { get; set; }
}
```